# IIS Express with VS2010 SP1 Constantly Rebuilds Web Site

Tags: asp.net, iis-express, visual-studio-2010

I'm working with larger solution that has several website projects and recently it was decided to switch from Cassini to IIS Express.  There are about 10 or so developers who all share the same solution/project and thus web.configs and they are all working happily with IIS Express except for me.  The problem is that for no pattern I can figure out, IIS Express constantly resets itself and performs a new build thus resetting the session.

Here are some of the reasons it will rebuild itself:

1. Editing an ASPX file
2. Doing nothing for a few minutes
3. Editing code behind file
4. Using the web site as normal

Note: the above actions do not always cause a rebuild.  Also many of these actions were perfectly fine using Cassini.

My system is pretty standard compared to the other developers who are not having issues.

Here is some more information:

- I'm using VS2010 SP1 and Windows 7 Professional.
- I started using IIS Express 7.0 but have since tried upgrading to 8 with the same results.
- I've uninstalled/reinstalled IIS Express several times w/o any luck.
- Using ReSharper 7.x
- I've turned off edit and continue

I'm now in full debug mode and this constant rebuild/reset is becoming prohibitive.

EDIT: it is in fact rebuilding as verified using health monitoring per John Saunders' suggestion.

EDIT: one important thing I did not mention is this mainly happens during a debug session.  Not only during debug session, but usually.  In fact adding a break point, or even hitting a break point can cause a rebuilt.

Comment: What leads you to believe it's a "rebuild"? Turn on ASP.NET Health Monitoring, and enable infrastructure events. You'll see in the Event Log exactly the reason for any resets.

Comment: I just hooked up health monitoring and yes it is rebuilding.  In fact I sometimes get:  "Application is shutting down. Reason: The BuildManager has made a change that requires the AppDomain to be shutdown" message.  But no always.

Comment: Look at the project's properties, is "Always start when debugging" set to False? If it's a Web Site project, also check the Property Pages to make sure "Build Web Site as part of the solution" is unchecked, and that "Start action" is set to "No build". And also check the web.config file, look for the `<system.web><compilation>` element and see if setting `batch="false"` makes any difference.

Comment: Could it be you have a plugin/addin in visual studio which edits code/comments or writes some metadata? O.o Just shot in the dark...

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Resharper as being the cause of the problem.  Try completely disabling or uninstalling Resharper and see if the problem persists.

I've been much happier with coderush from dev express myself...  I don't work for them just tried both and Resharper really bogged down my system and I didn't like it...