# Debugging website in VS 2012 and IIS Express 8.0 - keep losing session

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-express, vs-web-site-project

I recently installed VS2012 and my IIS Express automatically upgraded from 7.5 to 8.0.

Now whenever I debug a website application, I lose my session as if application is restarting every 2-3 pages.  By default website application auto-recompiles if you make like 15 changes to various pages, but I don't make any changes.  Just click on pages.

It happens in VS2012 and also in VS2010 which was working fine before I upgraded to VS 2012.

UPDATE 1: Very similar to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324342/iis-express-with-vs2010-sp1-constantly-rebuilds-web-site) that happens in VS2010 SP1.

Comment: have you found anything on this? keeps happening with VS 2013 as well

Comment: It's not an answer but [enabling health monitoring](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2008/02/18/monitoring-application-pool-and-application-restarts.aspx) might give you a bit more information, and [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1420538.aspx?Application+compilation+is+starting+Random+session+timeouts) post describes disabling anti-virus for _C:\windows\temp_ and your code directory. I'll report back if I ever solve my issue...